# wordpress, не подключает скрипт JS

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть данный код

```
  wp_register_script( 'requesthelpsteps-script-request-map', REQUESTHELP_PLUGIN_URL . 'js/RequestMap.js', '', '1.00', true );
if(is_page([
    'request-help',
    'request-help-2',
    'sample-page'
])){
    addAllStylesAndJsToPage();
}
function addAllStylesAndJsToPage() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script( 'requesthelpsteps-script-request-map' );
}
```

Но мой скрипт подключается только тогда, когда я залогинен в админку. Но как обычный пользователь - он не подключатся. Почему?
Как подключать его везде

Comment: выкаси админку на страничке и норм будет, не

Comment: Не понял ответ ваш

Comment: if ( ! current_user_can( ‘manage_options’ ) ) {
show_admin_bar( false );
} может так?